# An example of hermite interpolation

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, interpolation

I found this example on wikipedia. What I don't understand is that on the right hand side, the column starts with $-10$. Why isn't the column $-10, -4, 4, 10$? Why do the numbers in the middle place need to be divided by 2? Thanks!

Edit: Also why is the third number of the column starts with 15 1? $1-(-1)=2$?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recursion formula for divided differences is 
$$ f[x_n, \ldots, x_m] = \frac{f[x_n, \ldots, x_{m+1}] - f[x_{n-1},\ldots, x_m]}{x_n- x_m} $$
In the cases you mention, the differences in the denominator is $2$, so the difference is divided by $2$.

Comment: shouldn't the difference in the denominator be $0-(-1)=1$?

Comment: For the $1$ under the $15$ it is $z_6 - z_2 = 1 - (-1) = 2$.

Comment: Got it! What bout the -2 under the -10?

Comment: And also the column starts with 4

Comment: $z_6 - z_1  = 1 - (-1) = 2$.

Comment: Is there any trick for doing this? seems like I always find the wrong z

Comment: If you are confused, you can write down the "names" of the differences as it is done in first columns ...

Comment: got it! Thanks!